# Dieudonne determinant is well defined.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant, general-linear-group

Consider $GL_{n}(K)$ over field. By Dieudonne, $\forall A \in GL_{n}(K) \ (A = B*D(x))$ where $B$ is multiplication of some transvections and $D(x)=$

\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 0 &0& \dots \\
0 & 1&0& \dots & \\
    \vdots & & \dots & \\
    0 &    & \dots    & x
    \end{bmatrix}

-diagonal matrix with single last element, wich can be non unit. Its true, beacause invertable matrix has non-zero element on some $i$ position for each column $j$, we can add row $i$ to row $j+1$ and multiply by transvection $t_{j,j+1}(a_{j+1,j}^{-1}*(1-a_{j,j}))$ on the left, getting 1 on $a_{j,j}$ and subtracting multiples of $j$ row from other rows. And continue by induction untill last column, where $a_{n,n}$ can't be zero (otherwise other elements in column $n$ are zero, or we can express column $n$ as combination of other columns, each case mean, that $A$ isn't invertable), and finally we subtract multiples of $n$ row from other rows, getting result.
As soon as $D:GL_{n}(K) \rightarrow K$ is bijection, we can define determinant as $x$.

What i can't understand - is how to proove that such $x$ is unique.

Comment: As you can prove that $x = \det A$, it is unique.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, but we didn't proof that $det$ is well defined, or what do you mean?

Comment: Determinant. You have $\det A = \det B \det D(x)$, $\det B = 1$ as the determinant of any transvection is equal to $1$ and $\det D(x) = x$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, got it. We should define det some other way, show that it is homomorphism, giving 1 on $I$ and transvections (not changing with adding one row to another), and $det(A1, ..., b*Ai, ..., An)=b*det(A1, ..., Ai, ..., An)$. This is what Artin does. Thanks!